# Spark Scala - manipulate the current and the next element of a dataset of case class with field as sequence

Tags: scala

**Problem** :How to manipulate the current and the next elements of a sequence of case class. More details :
I have the result field as a sequence of ProceedResult as follow:

```
[
   [WrappedArray([1.955,89.105.200.57]),1], 
   [WrappedArray([3.103,185.147.12.11], [5.3575,185.147.12.31]),2], 
   [WrappedArray([3.143,185.147.12.19]),3], 
   [WrappedArray([3.678,160.242.100.88]),4], 
   [WrappedArray([6.082,196.216.48.144]),5], 
   [WrappedArray([7.711,193.239.116.112]),6], 
   [WrappedArray([8.228,192.5.5.241]),7]
]
```

each element of result is an object having a sequence of   ProceedSignal  (result field) and integer (hop field):

```
case class ProceedResult(
     var result: Seq[ProceedSignal],
     hop:        Int
)
```

and the

```
  case class ProceedSignal(
      medianRtt: Double,
      from:      String
  )
```

For example `[WrappedArray([1.955,89.105.200.57]),1]` is an instance of ProceedResult;

hop =1 and result's second element is : `WrappedArray([1.955,89.105.200.57])`
also,  `WrappedArray([1.955,89.105.200.57])` is instance of ProceedSignal where 1.955 is the medianRtt field and 89.105.200.57 is the from field.
The objective is to create a Link objects by combining the elements of each sequence with the elements of the next sequence. Given an example, 
[image]

*Use data of 1 and 2 is done by :*

iterate each element of 1 with each element of 2, so :

1. create a Link instance by using [1.955,89.105.200.57] and [3.103,185.147.12.11].
2. create a second Link instance by using [1.955,89.105.200.57] and [5.3575,185.147.12.31]

*Use data of 2 and 3 is done by :*

iterate each element of 2 with each element of 3, so :

1. create a Link instance by using [3.103,185.147.12.11] and [3.143,185.147.12.19].
2. create a Link instance by using [5.3575,185.147.12.31] and [3.143,185.147.12.19].

For information, Link case class is as  follow:

```
  case class Link(
     ip1:     String,
     ip2:     String,
     rttDiff: Double
  )
```

Hop that I give the enough information to help me.

Comment: Why is the question tagged [tag:apache-spark]? I don't see anything related to Spark in the question.

Comment: Because I use scala with Apache Spark. Maybe it is not clear in my question because I take a part of my code.

Comment: Can you fix the question to include parts that would be relevant for Apache Spark? If not, please remove the tag as there's nothing in the question that begs for it.